# Finding argmax indices along a dimension and negate the corresponding values if the index is 1

Tags: python-2.7, theano

Given a tensor in size DxCx2xHxW I try to find the argmax indices for the third dimension (between two values) and if the index is 0 I'll keep it or if it is 1 I'll negate the value and reduce the tensor to size DxCxHxW with the modified values and ignoring the non argmax indices.

Could you suggest a way to do this correctly? Thanks in advance for any further comment...

Here also my first stupid attempt that might give some insights about what am I trying to do.

```
max_val = self.pool_function(input_reshaped, axis=self.axis + 1) //input_rehshaed in size DxCx2xHxW
max_arg = T.argmax(input_reshaped, axis= self.axis+1)            //find argmax indices for the third dimension
return ifelse(T.lt(max_arg, 1), max_val, -max_val)               //negate argmax indices > 0 and return modified matrix ignoring the nonargmax indices
```

Answer (score 0):

For the potential benefit of other people, this question was answered on the theano-users mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/6P5KxLph2I8

The recommended solution, by Pierre Luc Carrier, was:

```
mask = input_reshaped.argmax(axis=3).astype("float32") * -2 + 1
return input_reshaped.max(axis=3) * mask
```